# What is the time complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: functions, gamma-function

I asked a [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67827/optimising-integer-division) on cs.stackexchange.com and I eventually (some days after) [answered](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/67899/62509) myself(After some research). I want to know the time complexity of my answer. But my math is too weak for it. I used Wolfram Alpha to arrive at a function for the time complexity of my answer.
I need to convert that function to Big-Oh notation.

Here's the relevant part of my answer:

> The usual worst case is when `a = 1`. The first instance will run $\lfloor{\lg b}\rfloor$ times. Then it's $\lfloor{\lg(\frac{b}{2})}\rfloor$, then $\lfloor{\lg(\frac{b}{4})}\rfloor$ until it gets to $\lfloor{\lg(\frac{b}{b})}\rfloor$ which will give 0.

This will give 
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \log_2\left(\frac{b}{2^i}\right)$$

This is equal to
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \log_2\left(\frac{2^n}{2^i}\right)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,  (1.0)$$
Because $b = 2^n$ (explained below).

> However if we denote $n$ by the number of bits needed to represent $b$, then $n = \lceil{\log_2(b)}\rceil$.
>   Thus, $b = 2^n - k$ where $k: 0 \le k \le 2^{n-1}$. To Big-Oh notation, $k$ is irrelevant, so we can just treat $b$ as $2^n$.

Plugging this into  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D+%5Clog_2%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B2%5En%7D%7B2%5Ei%7D%5Cright) yielded an unhelpful result.

Now to convert this to Big-Oh and Big-Theta Notation,.

I want to express $(1.0)$ as a Big-Theta function of $n$. Help please.

***EDIT***
There was a major error in my formula, I corrected it and it drastically changed the question, invalidating the original answer.

Comment: I think you have a typo: the sum on the LHS ranges over $i$, but the addends do not depend on $i$. So, perhaps you meant $$\sum_{i=0}^{b-1}\log_2(b-i)\qquad ?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now to convert this to Big-Theta Notation,.

Note, that $(1.0)$ is $\log_2(\frac{2^n}{2^0}) + \log_2(\frac{2^n}{2^1}) + \log_2(\frac{2^n}{2^2}) + \dots + \log_2(\frac{2^n}{2^n})$

Also note that $\frac{2^n}{2^i} = 2^{n-i}$
Also, $\log_2(2^{n-i}) = (n-i)(\log_2{2^2})$  this gives $n-i$

Thus, $(1.0)$ can be restated as:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n {n-i}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (2.0)$$ 
This ks the sum of the natural numbers to $n$ this gives 
$$\frac{n\cdot(n + 1)}{2} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (3.0)$$

We can see that $(3.0)$ is trivially $\Theta(n^2)$

Answer (score 1):

No need to complicate the things 
$$\log_2 b+\log_2 (b-1)+\log_2 (b-2)+........+\log_2 1=log_2(1\times 2\times......\times b)$$
$$=\log_2 b!=O(\log b^b)=O(b\log b)$$.
The r.h.s of your equation says the same thing.